# Widgets not responding on a PopUp Window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I Have designed 2 ui with Qt Designer and I import both of them to a new .py file which I use as the Main program. One is the Main window and the other is a custom popup Dialog. I was able to run the `MainWindow` without any trouble. I'm also able to Run the `Popup (QDialog, Modal)` but once it´s displayed, the widgets does not respond

Sorry for the question, but after looking online I just can´t get this to work and the big problem is that the compiler does not show me any error. The Code runs without a hassle, but the widgets won´t update/respond

I'm sorry if the Code is a bit messy, I learned Python last Month and PyQT last week.

Here is the code of the Program:

```
import sys
import _pickle as cPickle
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QPushButton, QWidget, QAction, QTabWidget,QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PedidoUI import Ui_MainWindow
from Emergente1 import Ui_Dialog


#I define a PopUp Dialog
class PopUp(Ui_Dialog):
    """docstring for PopUp"""
    def __init__(self,Dialog):
        Ui_Dialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(Dialog)
        self.botonAceptar.clicked.connect(self.AgregarItems)


#It should add the string "Prueba" as an Item to the list.
    def AgregarItems(self):
        self.listWidget.addItem("Prueba")


#This is the Main Class     
class ProgramaPedido(Ui_MainWindow): 
    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(MainWindow)


        self.Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
        self.ui = PopUp(self.Dialog)
        self.ui.setupUi(self.Dialog)

        self.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)

    #I call the PopUp   
    def open_dialog(self):

        self.Dialog.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    prog = ProgramaPedido(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the UI of MainWindow:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(642, 912)
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        MainWindow.setUnifiedTitleAndToolBarOnMac(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 10, 133, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 55, 19))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 510, 81, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.botonEnviar = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.botonEnviar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 540, 91, 41))
        self.botonEnviar.setObjectName("botonEnviar")
        self.botonDel = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.botonDel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 540, 41, 41))
        self.botonDel.setObjectName("botonDel")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 610, 61, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(520, 610, 69, 22))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 640, 181, 20))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.botonAdd = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.botonAdd.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 10, 75, 23))
        self.botonAdd.setObjectName("botonAdd")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 840, 101, 16))
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.BotonAdj = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.BotonAdj.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 470, 75, 23))
        self.BotonAdj.setObjectName("BotonAdj")
        self.botonAdjT = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.botonAdjT.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 470, 81, 23))
        self.botonAdjT.setObjectName("botonAdjT")
        self.BotonQuit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.BotonQuit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 470, 81, 23))
        self.BotonQuit.setObjectName("BotonQuit")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 80, 621, 381))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.listWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 540, 421, 291))
        self.listWidget_2.setObjectName("listWidget_2")
        self.comboBox_2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 171, 22))
        self.comboBox_2.setObjectName("comboBox_2")
        self.toolButton = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 50, 21, 21))
        self.toolButton.setObjectName("toolButton")
        self.toolButton_2 = QtWidgets.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(590, 610, 21, 21))
        self.toolButton_2.setObjectName("toolButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 642, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuConfiguracion = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuConfiguracion.setObjectName("menuConfiguracion")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionCorreo = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionCorreo.setObjectName("actionCorreo")
        self.actionPesta_as = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionPesta_as.setObjectName("actionPesta_as")
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuConfiguracion.menuAction())
        self.label.setBuddy(self.lineEdit)
        self.label_3.setBuddy(self.comboBox)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Articulo"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Pedido:"))
        self.botonEnviar.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enviar"))
        self.botonDel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "B"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Destino:"))
        self.botonAdd.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Agregar"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Nahuel Varela Blanco"))
        self.BotonAdj.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Adjuntar"))
        self.botonAdjT.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Adjuntar Todo"))
        self.BotonQuit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Quitar"))
        self.toolButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.toolButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.menuConfiguracion.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Configuracion"))
        self.actionCorreo.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Correo"))
        self.actionPesta_as.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Listas"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the Code of the PopUp dialog:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(356, 277)
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Dialog)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 10, 256, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.botonAceptar = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.botonAceptar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 250, 75, 23))
        self.botonAceptar.setObjectName("botonAceptar")
        self.botonAgr = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.botonAgr.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 210, 75, 23))
        self.botonAgr.setObjectName("botonAgr")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 210, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.botonBor = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.botonBor.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 240, 75, 23))
        self.botonBor.setObjectName("botonBor")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
        self.botonAceptar.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Aceptar"))
        self.botonAgr.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Agregar"))
        self.botonBor.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Borrar"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Change `def AgregarItems():` to `def AgregarItems(self):`

Comment: Saying that it does not work is not correct in SO. It is necessary in your description since saying the above could be interpreted in many ways. :P

Comment: Yes! I will Fix it!

Comment: It worked??????

Comment: no :(. I got the feeling that in some way I ´m not accessing the right Widget. When I run it with a type error in the name of the Widget (for example listWidget) of the PopUp, the compiler tells me that it does not exist, but when I type the name of the object right, it compiles wihout any errors, but the widget´s don´t update

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating objects of different classes. Qt Designer only provides a class that fills a widget, so it is not a widget, so the correct thing is to create a class that inherits the appropriate widget and uses the design, in general the class should have the following structure:

```
class Your_Widget(Widget_Class, Design_Class):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        Widget_Class.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Then we use it in the following way:

```
#I define a PopUp Dialog
class PopUp(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        QDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.botonAceptar.clicked.connect(self.AgregarItems)

    #It should add the string "Prueba" as an Item to the list.
    def AgregarItems(self):
        self.listWidget.addItem("Prueba")


#This is the Main Class     
class ProgramaPedido(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow): 
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.Dialog = PopUp()
        self.toolButton.clicked.connect(self.open_dialog)

    #I call the PopUp   
    def open_dialog(self):
        self.Dialog.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    prog = ProgramaPedido()
    prog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Ho yes! It worked! :D :D Thank you so much ! Wow, I can not belive that my code was so bad!